# How to differentiate "slow" VS "slowly" both as adverbs

Tags: differences, adverbs, flat-adverbs

I understand the 2 words are very simple words in English until I came across this sentence below:

---

"Please drive slow".

---

I know it should be an adverb here, and I checked it up to find "slow" is not only an adjective, but also an adverb. So my wondering is how to differentiate "slow" from "slowly" both as adverbs? For the sentence above, which sounds a bit weird though, is it also ok to say "Please drive slowly"?

Comment: It's a modern Americanizm that'll irritate you to no end now that you've noticed it. 'Real annoying', IMO.

Comment: Some people dislike *"Please speak slow"* but for some strange reason have fewer objections to the similar *"Please speak slower"*. [Google Ngrams suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speak+slow%2Cspeak+slower&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspeak%20slow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspeak%20slower%3B%2Cc0) this may be a recent development (though distorted in the charts by a phrase in James 1:19).

Comment: Well "slower" = "more slowly", so it works fine. But it should be "drive slowly".

Comment: related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/159278/a-slow-moving-vs-a-slowly-moving

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you are seeing here is a phenomenon called a "flat adverb". You might think of it as an adverb without the -ly suffix (though not always.) "Slow" as a flat adverb and "slowly" as a regular adverb have exactly the same meaning.

Flat adverbs were once quite common in English but have fallen out of favor, and often people who are sensitive about grammar will complain about sentences like "please drive slow", or "you are doing good". As to whether such things are "right" or not I think it is hard to say, since English does not have some body that defines the language. What is "right" is what the educated and literate do with the language, and flat adverbs are still quite common, even though many would cringe at the aforementioned "you are doing good", most would not be too concerned with "please drive slow."

For sure there are some flat adverbs where there is no -ly alternative, for example, "Please drive fast" must be used instead of some putative "Please drive fastly", even though "Please drive quick" and "please drive quickly" are both common and widely accepted.

So the answer to your question: how to decide which to use where is simply that there is no rule, you can often substitute a flat adverb for a regular adverb, but you do run the risk of being criticized nit-pickingly, if you'll excuse such a word. Except in those few cases where a flat adverb is the only alternative. You can usually be safe by using the -ly, or equivalent, form, except in those few cases where such a word does not exist, or where there is a specific idiom. "Please sit tightly", "take it easily" or "drive straightly down the street" all sound pretty odd, for example.

Some more info on this at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb) or the ever enjoyable ["Ask the editor"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7epnfcHy5SA) at Merriam Webster.

Comment: Also to be considered is that street signs are like headlines, where short forms are common to fit space and allow for a quick read. Drive slow. Keep right. No turn on red.

Comment: ["Superman does good. You're doing _well_."](https://youtu.be/LoE8ZgzaX7A?t=16)

Comment: Plus one for "nitpickingly."  You did swell-ly.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd never heard of flat adverbs and had always believed that "drive slow" was  an error.  I must admit, knowing "slow" it a legitimate adverb doesn't make "drive slow" sound any less cringe-inducing to me.

Comment: Your answer contains a run-on sentence, specifically a comma-splice, and a misuse of the colon. "So the answer to your question: how to decide which to use where is simply that there is no rule, you can often substitute a flat adverb for a regular..." Consider instead: "The answer to your question of how to decide which form to use is simply that there is no rule. You can often substitute a flat adverb for a regular..."

Comment: Is it ironic that, for an answer on flat adverbs, someone with the username @Flater gave the classic criticism of flat adverbs?

Comment: Missionaries do good; businesses do well. It's a useful distinction. We have the word "well"; why not put it to use.

Comment: Drive slow - sounds like a sign board. How is it that 'Drive slowly' is less preferred? Even I haven't heard about flat adverb or so.

Comment: "Drive slowly" is common in the UK on signage. "Please drive slowly through our village" is commonly seen.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Perhaps "drive safe!" is less uncommon; [Scott Manley](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxzC4EngIsMrPmbm6Nxvb-A) always ends his videos with a "Fly safe!". There may also be a fuzzy area between flat adverbs and ["depictive constructions"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/46391/15471). In that post, a good example is given: "John left the party angry". That may not have been his manner of leaving, but the *state* in which he left. "Drive safe" may not (only) mean that I change my manner of operating a car, but (also) the wish that I be in a safe state while I'm driving.

Comment: One could argue that "drive slow" is an elided form of "drive at a slow speed," making "slow" an adjective, not an adverb in that case. I'm OK with very short and ungrammatical phrases for signs, but not in careful writing and speech.

Comment: Does this apply only to AmEng? It sounds terrible to me as a native BrEng speaker. Acceptable in a traffic sign, perhaps [though even then I'd prefer not], but certainly not in 'educated' writing. I was always taught along the lines of "It is a fast car, you can drive it quickly".

Comment: @Tetsujin I did not want to put this in my original answer since I have only anecdotal support. However, I have lived in both Britain and the US for many years and in my experience flat adverbs are considerably more common in the US than the UK.

Comment: @kaz English has lots of synonyms, how barren would our language be without them. I think flat adverbs have a certain bristling intensity that is lacking in their regular companions. "You did good!" while semantically equivalent, has a different color, a different flavor to "You did well!". Life with only vanilla ice cream would be all the poorer.